# New Folder option not working after uninstalling Q-Dir

Tags: windows-7, windows, qdir

I uninstalled Q-Dir for something I'm working on.
When i tried the regular explorer, the New Folder is not working.
Also tried the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> ; <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Also tried updating regedit with this and still no luck with the New Folder:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
@="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
@="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\DesktopBackground\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
@="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"
```

mkdir is working with cmd.Tried reinstalling Q-Dir and still doesnt have the New Folder option.
Im using Windows 7 Enterprise, and system restore is disabled by the company.

Comment: See accepted answer on this page....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/97de8a2a-12f2-4381-a409-a78f4ae551cf/cannot-create-new-folder-in-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: Thanks! The .reg worked. Though I received some errors when I ran it that some of the lines were not executed.

Comment: I think it depends if it is 32bit or 64bit windows, some of the reg entries do not exist. Glad you got it sorted.